# Mock Future object

Tags: java, mockito, future

I have a problem with throw InterruptedException.
Part of my source:

```
    Future<Object> future = mock(Future.class);
    when(future.get(any(), any())).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());
```

But I get java.lang.NullPointerException on the second line, What's wrong with my code? I want to throw InterruptedException when I call get method

Comment: Have you used a Debugger?

Comment: `Mockito#any` returns `null`. `Future#get` expects a `long`. During the unboxing conversion, the `NullPointerException` is thrown. You could fix this with `any(Long.class)`, where it will return a non-null default value for the `Long` type.

Comment: thanks a lot! I change to anyLong() and it works